# Is there a way to appendTo head?

Tags: jquery

I'm working with a platform that doesn't allow me to edit the source code. Is there a way to insert a line in the head element dynamically? Maybe something like below...

```
$("<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle' rel='stylesheet'>").appendTo("head")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) as you have it should work perfectly fine. As well as this one:

```
$('head').append("<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle' rel='stylesheet'>");
```

but here's how I would write it:

```
$('head').append(
    $('<link/>', {
        href: 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle',
        rel: 'stylesheet'
    })
);
```

Comment: Ah jeez, there I go not trying something first hand and doubting myself again from the get go. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you write it like you did? Is that just a more elegant way?

Comment: @J82, yes, I find it more elegant and this method also has the advantage of ensuring that DOM elements are properly formed and quotes and double quotes not mixed. I try to avoid using strings when working with the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
$("head").append("<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle' rel='stylesheet'>")
```